# Crash on change to Core Data after migration

Tags: ios, core-data

So I am having a weird crash I hope someone can read the crash data. I built a Core Data model about a month ago for an app. It's 12 entities and each entity has several relationships to the other entities. About two weeks ago (after a Test Flight), I wanted to update the model. I versioned the model, add the two flags (NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption) to the creation of the persistentStoreCoordinator and made my changes. I booted the app, the model was migrated and I was on my way. Since then, I have made other changes to Version 2 of the data model without any difficulty. Today, I added one Boolean Attribute to one entity and now the app crashes at launch. If I delete the newly added attribute, the app works fine. I am struggling to understand how over the past two weeks I have added attributes, entities, even relationships to Version 2 without hitch. Is this Boolean flag the proverbial straw? Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Here's the crash log:

```
2015-03-18 22:01:16.778 GroupShop[67338:2060644] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/tom/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0FD3C702-3CB8-49AA-AA22-72FED2328608/data/Containers/Data/Application/37785998-3FC9-4C96-ADD4-920BAAB1CCFD/Documents/store.data options:{
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x7fb9733d86e0 {URL=file:///Users/tom/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0FD3C702-3CB8-49AA-AA22-72FED2328608/data/Containers/Data/Application/37785998-3FC9-4C96-ADD4-920BAAB1CCFD/Documents/store.data, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        GSFullImage = <c5bc1212 ba535c9d d2c71ba9 7698bd48 d5389868 79acddbf 227ac7bd 41050fe6>;
        GSGroupShop = <c272e62b 995b4e9f e361e6a1 77357123 2d16180f c14360b6 e5280119 3fbcb50c>;
        GSInvites = <d8858c72 6de5f142 04fbd267 10879385 4cb3ed6c 7d7c0e21 e2eae506 482b74f7>;
        GSItem = <f200451b 61aefbb4 5f0fd9a3 7ce920b6 0da9ce90 871b1178 b818ad43 5548cfe5>;
        GSItemCategory = <9e9259dc f21358fe 5e7666f2 05385024 ce03a9c4 1456b8d0 3cd8ee14 5ada76b8>;
        GSLocation = <77f18fda 31ab27c1 0b678c32 02df009d bd6aa02a 04efae2f b7f95f16 be9c41dd>;
        GSMembers = <59b2dc70 bda93cbd 594ed99e aed5f90e 2dcc17bf 2bd4cdc7 9ee21421 91c975a6>;
        GSMessageText = <eaa0bb73 1c2dbf25 bba2d857 e56c45fa 245fe57e e67970ab 5ba0faba 5662d028>;
        GSNotificationDetail = <f3cd7739 2b3b20c8 1a42784f a91ba748 98b93346 585dcf5e 1b141ec6 6f613676>;
        GSOpinion = <c4567265 e5a04989 c3fd25b5 20603c9f 12a769fc 5a03e791 5f68c11b cd1e1e83>;
        GSPermissions = <efd97c2b 21640078 d3a955bc bf79fa0d b521d884 8d561cc5 ac4a0053 4cd4cad4>;
        GSShoppingItems = <0677f34f 61487e6f 06bdcd5f 3508f95a 0f383320 39dde01f 733afb3a 6cec1343>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "B8C295E3-8527-4438-BB39-6CBAFAF97194";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store} with userInfo dictionary {
    URL = "file:///Users/tom/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0FD3C702-3CB8-49AA-AA22-72FED2328608/data/Containers/Data/Application/37785998-3FC9-4C96-ADD4-920BAAB1CCFD/Documents/store.data";
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            GSFullImage = <c5bc1212 ba535c9d d2c71ba9 7698bd48 d5389868 79acddbf 227ac7bd 41050fe6>;
            GSGroupShop = <c272e62b 995b4e9f e361e6a1 77357123 2d16180f c14360b6 e5280119 3fbcb50c>;
            GSInvites = <d8858c72 6de5f142 04fbd267 10879385 4cb3ed6c 7d7c0e21 e2eae506 482b74f7>;
            GSItem = <f200451b 61aefbb4 5f0fd9a3 7ce920b6 0da9ce90 871b1178 b818ad43 5548cfe5>;
            GSItemCategory = <9e9259dc f21358fe 5e7666f2 05385024 ce03a9c4 1456b8d0 3cd8ee14 5ada76b8>;
            GSLocation = <77f18fda 31ab27c1 0b678c32 02df009d bd6aa02a 04efae2f b7f95f16 be9c41dd>;
            GSMembers = <59b2dc70 bda93cbd 594ed99e aed5f90e 2dcc17bf 2bd4cdc7 9ee21421 91c975a6>;
            GSMessageText = <eaa0bb73 1c2dbf25 bba2d857 e56c45fa 245fe57e e67970ab 5ba0faba 5662d028>;
            GSNotificationDetail = <f3cd7739 2b3b20c8 1a42784f a91ba748 98b93346 585dcf5e 1b141ec6 6f613676>;
            GSOpinion = <c4567265 e5a04989 c3fd25b5 20603c9f 12a769fc 5a03e791 5f68c11b cd1e1e83>;
            GSPermissions = <efd97c2b 21640078 d3a955bc bf79fa0d b521d884 8d561cc5 ac4a0053 4cd4cad4>;
            GSShoppingItems = <0677f34f 61487e6f 06bdcd5f 3508f95a 0f383320 39dde01f 733afb3a 6cec1343>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "B8C295E3-8527-4438-BB39-6CBAFAF97194";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "Can't find model for source store";
}
2015-03-18 22:01:16.781 GroupShop[67338:2060644] CoreData: annotation: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's current model hashes are {
    GSFullImage = <c5bc1212 ba535c9d d2c71ba9 7698bd48 d5389868 79acddbf 227ac7bd 41050fe6>;
    GSGroupShop = <e46044b3 50e03456 805a1c17 ef91b2f7 11c7c064 12c8ca8a a23388c5 970125c1>;
    GSInvites = <d8858c72 6de5f142 04fbd267 10879385 4cb3ed6c 7d7c0e21 e2eae506 482b74f7>;
    GSItem = <f200451b 61aefbb4 5f0fd9a3 7ce920b6 0da9ce90 871b1178 b818ad43 5548cfe5>;
    GSItemCategory = <9e9259dc f21358fe 5e7666f2 05385024 ce03a9c4 1456b8d0 3cd8ee14 5ada76b8>;
    GSLocation = <77f18fda 31ab27c1 0b678c32 02df009d bd6aa02a 04efae2f b7f95f16 be9c41dd>;
    GSMembers = <59b2dc70 bda93cbd 594ed99e aed5f90e 2dcc17bf 2bd4cdc7 9ee21421 91c975a6>;
    GSMessageText = <eaa0bb73 1c2dbf25 bba2d857 e56c45fa 245fe57e e67970ab 5ba0faba 5662d028>;
    GSNotificationDetail = <f3cd7739 2b3b20c8 1a42784f a91ba748 98b93346 585dcf5e 1b141ec6 6f613676>;
    GSOpinion = <c4567265 e5a04989 c3fd25b5 20603c9f 12a769fc 5a03e791 5f68c11b cd1e1e83>;
    GSPermissions = <efd97c2b 21640078 d3a955bc bf79fa0d b521d884 8d561cc5 ac4a0053 4cd4cad4>;
    GSShoppingItems = <0677f34f 61487e6f 06bdcd5f 3508f95a 0f383320 39dde01f 733afb3a 6cec1343>;
}
2015-03-18 22:01:16.831 GroupShop[67338:2060644] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Open Failure', reason: 'Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ce84a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bfe2bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ce849ad +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   GroupShop                           0x000000010b416813 -[GSDataAccess initPrivate] + 867
    4   GroupShop                           0x000000010b416472 __32+[GSDataAccess sharedDataAccess]_block_invoke + 50
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001107fb614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001107e7881 dispatch_once_f + 565
    7   GroupShop                           0x000000010b41641d +[GSDataAccess sharedDataAccess] + 141
    8   GroupShop                           0x000000010b3a7066 -[GSUtility initSimple] + 182
    9   GroupShop                           0x000000010b3a6f72 __26+[GSUtility sharedUtility]_block_invoke + 50
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001107fb614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001107e7881 dispatch_once_f + 565
    12  GroupShop                           0x000000010b3a6f1d +[GSUtility sharedUtility] + 141
    13  GroupShop                           0x000000010b3b20e5 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 581
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010ddf3458 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 248
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010ddf4002 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2540
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010ddf6e3e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010ddf5d35 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000112728243 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cdb9c7c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cdaf9c5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cdaf183 __CFRunLoopRun + 851
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cdaebc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010ddf57a2 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010ddf8580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    25  GroupShop                           0x000000010b408033 main +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't keep changing the same model version and expect Core Data to keep up. The migration options you're using only apply when the data doesn't match the current model version but **does** match some older version included in your app. With automatic lightweight migration, Core Data figures out how to update your persistent store to use the new model. If you change the *same* version of the model, you may prevent Core Data from matching the persistent store file to *any* model version, and then you get this exception.

You mention that you made some changes and it worked. Not every change affects the version hash for the model. A Core Data model is uniquely identified by the version hashes of its entities as returned by the `[NSEntityDescription versionHash]`. That in turn depends on the result of the value of `versionHash` on `NSRelationshipDescription`, `NSAttributeDescription`, and `NSPropertyDescription`. Some minor changes don't affect any version hashes. In general changes don't affect the version hash unless they affect the formatting of data in the underlying SQLite file.

**Adding a new attribute will change the `versionHash` of the `NSEntityDescription`**, which is why you're having this problem. If you were still migrating data from your original model, it would still work. It's only a problem because you have data that used a model version that doesn't match anything in your app right now.

To fix, do one of the following:

- Create a new third model version with this change and migrate to that, or
- Remove your existing data and migrate version 1--> 2 again, or
- Undo this most recent change so that your data continues to match your latest model version.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. Core Data is still black box for me. I created a third model and made the changes there, it seems to be working. Once I ship the product, it there a way to "collapse" the models or will I just have a long list of models as the product grows?

Comment: The shipped version of the app needs to contain the current model version plus every version that a user might be upgrading from. It can get to be a lot if the model changes frequently. You don't need to include model versions used only during development that were never released in previous app versions. If a user might have old data using a particular model version, that model version needs to be available in the app.